# C++ #define preprocessor directive is not recognized after "<text>"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, preprocessor-directive

I have some problem in connection with C++ in MS VS 2015 Enterprise.

I have got a preprocessor directive, in \Str.h

```
\\ \Str.h file
Line 96: #define S_COLOR_RED "^1"
```

and used it for example at these lines:

```
\\ \math\Simd.cpp file
Line 1501: idLib::common->Printf( "   simd->Memcpy() "S_COLOR_RED"X\n" );
Line 1527: idLib::common->Printf( "   simd->Memset() "S_COLOR_RED"X\n" );
```

The problem is, if there is a "" before the directive, the C++ wants to use it as user-defined literal, but in fact it is just a simple defined constant.

After changing to the following, it works:

```
// \math\Simd.cpp
Line 1527: idLib::common->Printf( "   simd->Memset() "
Line 1527: idLib::common->Printf( S_COLOR_RED"X\n" );
```

What could cause this? All credit goes for id Tech, because these code pieces from id Tech 4 engine. I haven't made any modification in the original code, just trying to solve errors from the downloaded source.

I tried to search for more information about this problem, without results.

Thank you for your help,
Sanapci

Comment: Can't reproduce this error: http://ideone.com/FF6nTx Maybe a whitespace between macro and strings will help?

Comment: Uhm, yes whitespace is a solution, too. :)
How do I forget to try this.. Thank you.

In my question forget to post error code:
`Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error C3688 invalid literal suffix 'S_COLOR_RED'; literal operator or literal operator template 'operator ""S_COLOR_RED' not found idLib C:\Users\sanap\Desktop\TTimo-doom3.gpl-1559777\neo\idlib\math\Simd.cpp 1501`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
dLib::common->Printf( "   simd->Memcpy() " S_COLOR_RED "X\n");
                                          ^           ^
                                          space between
```

The string literals will concatenate if you put a space between them.

Comment: Yes, after Anedar comment I tried this method and worked. :)
Thanks for your answer too, But I suppose it used to work in this form and did not know that why occurs.